# ”CSVはUTF-8エンコードされていません”対処方法

Tags: python3, csv, jupyter-lab

環境は Windows10, Jupyter Lab です。

私はあるコードを実行して、Jupyter Labのデスクトップに出力された
CSVファイルをクリックすると、以下のエラーが出ました。

添付[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

で、CSVファイルを右クリックし”ダウンロード”をクリックすると
エクセルファイルで表示され、開きます。
又、エクスプローラーで見るCSVは、クリックすると開きます。

で、上記画像のエラー文を検索して、解決を試みました。

試み一、

```
nkf -w --overwrite sample.csv
```

結果、SyntaxError: invalid syntax

試み二、

```
with open('sjis.txt', encoding='shift_jis') as f:
    s = f.read()

print(s.strip())
```

結果、FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sjis.txt'

試み三、

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("sample.csv", encoding="SHIFT_JIS")
```

結果、FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sample.csv'

試み四、

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option(‘display.max_rows’, 10)
```

結果、SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

試み五、

```
df = pd.read_csv(‘sample.csv’, encoding = ‘shift-jis’, index_col = 1)
df
```

結果、SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

試み六、

```
import csv

with open('sampl.csv', encoding="utf_8") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)

    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

結果、FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sampl.csv'

以上ですが、ご教授お願い致します。

Comment: エラーメッセージを読む気はないのでしょうか？

Comment: エラーメッセージに基づいて解決を試みましたが…結果解決できず。で、エラーがエラーを”呼び…”。で、”羅列”したのは、自分の解決過程を書いた方がいいかなと思って、この様に書きましたが…不快感を与えたならお詫び申し上げます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

単に文字コードを変換したいのであれば、初めのエラーになった CSV ファイルを Windows のメモ帳で開き、ファイルメニューの「名前を付けて保存」で表示されたダイアログで、「文字コード」のプルダウンから「UTF-8」を選んで上書き保存してみてください。

Comment: 解決、出来ました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

`iconv`コマンド、ありますよね。
sample.csvがシフトJISなら

```
iconv -f SJIS -t UTF-8 saple.csv -o sample_utf8.csv
```

sample.csvの文字コードを確認するには

```
type sample.csv
```

Comment: あ、Windowsでしたか…

Comment: Windowsならこちらのページを参考にしてみてください。

[CSVファイルの文字コードを「UTF-8」に変換する方法は？ – AD2カスタマーサポート](https://ad2.zendesk.com/hc/ja/articles/360009714573-CSV%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%92-UTF-8-%E3%81%AB%E5%A4%89%E6%8F%9B%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95%E3%81%AF-)

Comment: ご助言、ありがとうございます。